# What precisely (if anything) should be tagged pedagogy?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [pedagogy](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) gets a lot of usage, possibly too much. I propose a discussion to sharpen the meaning of this tag (or to replace it by more specific ones).

The current tag wiki says:

> Pedagogy questions ask how to help students learn something.

This seems so broad, it makes it almost empty.

Comment: FYI, it is possible to blacklist a tag and show users who attempt to use it a message like “The tag pedagogy is ambiguous, please use either [tag:mathematical-pedagogy] or [tag:general-pedagogy] instead”. You need to ask a Stack Exchange employee to set this up.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that this tag is used very broadly, and that there is a variety of types of questions which uses this tag. The following list is not intended to be complet, but tries to classify the zoo of questions we have.

- Questions which are concered with course design, like [On the use of calculators in elementary/high school? Computer algebra systems later on?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/270/on-the-use-of-calculators-in-elementary-high-school-computer-algebra-systems-la) and [Why teach back substitution with row reduction?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/202/why-teach-back-substitution-with-row-reduction). These questions about a certain method or technique and ask about the pedagogical implications of this, including the how and the why. I'd rather call these didactical questions than pedagogical ones.
- Questions which ask about the teacher-student interaction in a specific situation, such as [Teaching somebody else's class](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/469/teaching-somebody-elses-class). Imho, these kind of questions are the ones which fit best into this category.
- Meta-questions concerned with pedagogics itself like [Is there a tag/competence classification for mathematics education?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/318/is-there-a-tag-competence-classification-for-mathematics-education).

Comment: It is useful to have this information handy, thank you! For the first type I guess the existing [tag:course-design] is good. For the last we might needs some tag, not sure which one. At the moment there is also a [tag:meta] for this, but that one absolutely must be renamed, IMO. Also the middle category feels not really specific.

Answer (score 4):

I vote for removing the tag altogether in favor of more specific tags. Pretty much every question about education could easily be construed as having to do with pedagogy.

Comment: I also think, it is too broad. Do you have any suggestions for more specific tags?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I am about to start implementing this. Please speak up in case of objections, better ideas, and so on.

---

I propose the creation of one or two somewhat general tags to be used for some of the questions now tagged [pedagogy](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy):

1. general-pedagoy: for questions touching upon pedagogical considerations and problems of a general nature, i.e., not specific to mathematics. Please note that some aspect of the question should still be related to mathematics.
2. mathematical-pedagogy: for questions on general considerations and problems of teaching mathematics, i.e., issues specfic to teaching mathematics yet relevant to various contexts and courses.

Maybe one, then named general-pedagogy, could suffice with a slightly broader description then. But at the moment I am leaning towards having both.

None of them should be used too freqently, but only if it is really a rather general question.